# useState() and setList not working properly in React Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[image: this is mockData.js which has list of restaurants]

[image: this is Body Component. I have created a useState of data from mockdata.js and used it to fill each object from it (using map function) in Restaurantcard component and also it has a button on Rwhose click, it filters those restaurants that have avgRating greater than 4 and sets it to the useState variable listofRestaurant]

I am constantly getting error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

I have no idea what is wrong with my code.

Analysis - it renders the page initially with all restaurants nicely! you can see restaurant component below with map() function.

It takes each restaurant and sends to restaurantCard component and it renders perfectly, but the issue arises when I click the button.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please put the code in the question as text, not an image. And the bug is that `filteredList` is an array, while `mockData` is an object with a `.restaurants` property. You'll want the state to be the same shape before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem is in initialization and in for map loop.

The solution

```js
// create hook like this
const [listOfRestuarants, setListOfRestuarants] = useState(mockData.restuarants);
```

in JSX use the below code

```js
// create hook like this
listOfRestuarants.map((card) => (<Restuarant key={card.id} restData={card} />))
```

This will solve your problem.

The actual problem is in initialization where you are setting up an object but when you click on the button you are applying the filter which returns the array.

Comment: mockdata.info gave the error... do you mean mockData.restaurants?  Also, when I did mockData.restaurants in useState it worked! I have a query, why did we need to add mockData.restaurants? at initial render, it worked but after btn click when we used filter, how it changed the object?

Comment: Also, why if I use mockData only in useState and use listOfRestuarants.restaurants at all other places, then it does'nt work but when we use mockData.restaurants in useState but listOfRestuarants in all other places, then it worked???

Comment: @Rocko: Because you've confused yourself with your own data structure.  `mockData` is not an array, it's an object.  That object has a property called `restaurants`.  So your initial state is an object with a property called `restaurants`, which the rendering code uses.  But later you update your state to be *just an array*.  An array has no property called `restaurants`.  So the rendering logic fails.  The takeaway here is to keep your data structures consistent.